# NLP Huggingface Tokenizer wont let me set pre_tokenizer property

Tags: nlp, huggingface

I was using Huggingface Transformer's models and classes for some time now. I used it as an "off the shelf" product, following many tutorials all over the internet, to develop very interesting apps like a chatbot and a tweet generator. Very nice framework or library or whatever you may call it this days.

Now I want to dig a little deeper and try to customize some of the steps in what Hugginface calls the Pipeline. The Pipeline is an encapsulation or a bundle of different classes that perform all the different steps needed to generate text, translation, sentiment analysis or any other result you may be looking for in a NLP application.

With this in mind, I started to study the Tokenizer class as the first step in the pipeline. There are several tokenizers available to work with. So I peek one and follow the [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/index) provided by Huggingface to customize it and eventually train it.

At some point the tutorial explains how to change the pre_tokenizer by setting the property pre_tokenizer to a new instance of some PreTokenizer class of your choice.

here is the snippet:

```
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Whitespace
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import BPE

tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE(unk_token="[UNK]"))
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()
```

I'm coding in Python using JetBrains PyCharm free edition and I get the warning:

**Property 'pre_tokenizer' cannot be set**

**Inspection info: Reports cases when properties are accessed inappropriately:**

The property is not set but the script runs fine.

The same happens with **tokenizer.normalizer**. Property 'normalizer' cannot be set.

I couldn't find any comment about that.
I'm probably doing something wrong.
Can anybody help me with this problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: I decided to try with a pre trained tokenizer. It works fine. Accepts the pre_tokenizer setting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using IntelliJ with the python plugin.

But when I checked by printing the property it seems to be set nonetheless

```
from tokenizers.models import BPE
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.normalizers import NFKC, Sequence

tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE())
print(tokenizer.normalizer)
tokenizer.normalizer = Sequence([NFKC()])
print(tokenizer.normalizer)
```